# Cannot convert an object to a string-array in vb.net but I can in C#.net (core)

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, python.net

I cannot cast an object to a string-array (or collection) in VB.net, I am able to do it in C#.

VB.net code:

```vb
Runtime.PythonDLL = "/usr/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so"
Using Py.GIL
    Dim APT As Object = Py.Import("apt")
    Dim Cache As Object = APT.Cache()
    Dim PyObj As Object = Cache.keys()
    Dim PKGs As String() = CType(PyObj, String())
End Using
```

I get the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'Python.Runtime.PyObject' to type 'System.String[]'.`

C#.net code which work:

```cs
Runtime.PythonDLL = "/usr/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so";
using (Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic APT = Py.Import("apt");   // Type: dynamic {Python.Runtime.PyModule}, <module 'apt' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py'>
    dynamic Cache = APT.Cache();      // Type: dynamic {Python.Runtime.PyModule}, <apt.cache.Cache object at 0x7fa701ec6760>
    dynamic PyObj = Cache.keys();     // Type: dynamic {Python.Runtime.PyModule}, ['0ad', '0ad-data',...]
    String[] PKGs = (String[])PyObj;
}
```

I see the same in the debugger for vb.net and C#.net.

Debugger in vb.net:

[image]

Debugger in C#.net:

[image]

I'm aware I use the `dynamic` type in C# and `Object` in VB. I do use option strict=Off in VB.
As fare I know VB doesn't have `dynamic` but I assume you can use `Object` instead if strict=Off.
Maybe that's the reason and it's just not possible?

I also tried to convert to:

- arraylist
- List(of String)
- HasetSet(of String)
- Dictionary(Of String, Object)

Tried both **TryCast**, **DirectCast** and **CType**.

Comment: Try [`CTypeDynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.conversion.ctypedynamic).

Comment: Ahh....nice, look like it could be the solution :-) But I see it was introduced in .core 3.0 and I still haven't upgrade from 2.2 yet so I can't confirm yet. I did though find a method in the Python.net library which do the conversion.

Comment: Glad you found a way to convert to the needed type. FYI: [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) creates a  `DLR` object. As you discovered, this is *not* the same as a non-strict VB object. Hence the newer `CTypeDynamic` as per Jeroen's comment. But `DynamicObject` class has been around since .core 1.1, so I suspect there was *some* way to do it in VB, even without `CTypeDynamic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the solution from @Jeroen Mostert, which I prefer as it's more universal , I did find a method in the Python.net library that do the job: `pyObject.As<T>()`

```vb
Runtime.PythonDLL = "/usr/lib/python3.9/config-3.9-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.9.so"
Using Py.GIL
   Dim APT As Object = Py.Import("apt")
   Dim Cache As Object = APT.Cache()
   Dim PyObj As PyObject = Cache.keys()
   Dim PKGs As String() = PyObj.As(Of String())() '<==========
   Console.WriteLine(PKGs(0))
End Using
PythonEngine.BeginAllowThreads() 'Must be called to release the Py.GIL thread!
```